# cassandra nodetool/cqlsh describe cluster

Tags: cassandra, range, cql, nodetool

I am testing Cassandra on a 3 nodes cluster on Google cloud and trying to see the Ranges Ownership distribution between the nodes ( I have an RF = 3 for the test keyspace). I have tried both CQL describe cluster and Nodetool describecluster but none of them shows as well the ranges (only snitch, partitioner and schema versions). Running cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.9 | CQL spec 3.4.2 . Any idea how can I find this info or why these commands don't display these? Might be because of the cluster setup? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From within CQL, you can query the `system.local` table.  This table exists on each node, contains only a single row, and holds data specific to the node itself.  The `tokens` column contains the same data as is returned via the `nodetool ring` command:

```
> SELECT tokens FROM system.local ;

 tokens
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {'-1221474524472000659', '-2679404716758606376', '-9167452864191410895', '-9208108764127114640', '1685199701625160019', '1767371464207122869', '5004977198676178684', '5337137237744686089', '6630117681615088706', '7106607077939671384', '7512974951531203644', '8229478807809310370'}

(1 rows)
```

Note that querying `tokens` via `system.local` returns only the token ranges for the current node.  To see them for another node in the cluster, you can query the `tokens` column on the `system.peers` table, where they are keyed by IP Address (`peer`).

```
> SELECT tokens FROM system.peers WHERE peer='192.168.6.114';

 tokens
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {'-4094626707569673185', '-5633637686310353556', '-6167080457205238021', '-6475599470116582717', '-6726897113409283403', '-7185540759553541576', '-7282762652579832116', '-7740824590733013501', '-8045274855112430621', '2064433256459654945', '667061811731435593', '7079292008020861651'}

(1 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron, is there by any chance a possibility to see the ranges distribution per Column Family?

Comment: @Vcrisan The ranges are the set by node, and will be the same for all tables (column families) with data on that node.  That's why things like logged atomic batches work across different tables, because the partition keys are hashed the same regardless of which table they are in.

Answer (score 0):

can you try `nodetool ring`

The token column provides the  end of the token range up to and including the value listed.

Read here https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsRing.html